# Is there a horizontal expanding listview for android?

Tags: android, listview

[image: horizontal expanding listview]

I did a mockup to describe my request. Is there some listview in android like this or do i have to code it myself?

Comment: It's actually 3 list views in several horizontal tabs. What is the maximum depth?

Comment: so what does it do just show different results based on your selection? You can just use a `viewpager` with 3 listviews for this